# sort in alphabetical order subset of columns in pandas datafram

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge dataset with more than 900 columns. Part of the columns are languages of the world. I want to sort this subset of columns from my dataset in alphabetical order. My solution was to slice the dataset, assign this subset to another variable and sort the columns. Now, I am trying to replace the unsorted subset by the sorted subset, but the code below did not do the job.

```
lang_columns1=survey.iloc[:,19:104] #assigning subset of columns to a variable

lang_columns_sorted1 =lang_columns1.reindex(sorted(lang_columns1.columns), axis=1) 
#sorting columns in alphabetical order by name

survey.iloc[:,19:104] = lang_columns_sorted1 #replacing the unsorted columns by the sorted columns
```

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by joined all columns:

```
s = survey.columns.to_series()
survey.columns = [s, s.groupby(s).cumcount()]

cols = survey.columns[:19].tolist() + 
       sorted(survey.columns[19:104], key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])) + 
       survey.columns[104:].tolist()

survey = survey.reindex(cols, axis=1).droplevel(1, axis=1)
```

Comment: with this code do I sort the columns by name without changing the original values?

Comment: @NatáliaResende - I hope so.

Comment: Just realised that this code does not work because there are two subsets of columns with the same names in the same dataset. columns 19:104 has unsorted language names and also columns 113:198.  I want to sort both subsets. The code worked on a toy df,  but it does not work in the real data. I got a warning concerning the duplicate axis. I tried: cols = survey.columns[:19].tolist() + sorted(survey.columns[19:104]) + survey.columns[104: 113].tolist() +  sorted(survey.columns[113:198])+ survey.columns[198:].tolist()
survey = survey.reindex(cols, axis=1), but got the same error

Comment: @NatáliaResende - can you test now?